# Handling time consuming requests in Flask-UWSGI app

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Am running an app with Flask , UWSGI and Nginx. My UWSGI is set to spawn out 4 parallel processes to handle multiple requests at the same time. Now I have one request that takes lot of time and that changes important data concerning the application. So, when one UWSGI process is processing that request and say all others are also busy, the fifth request would have to wait. The problem here is I cannot change this request to run in an offline mode as it changes important data and the user cannot simply remain unknown about it. What is the best way to handle this situation ?

Comment: You can run the data change in the background and let the user poll (via javascript) wether the data change was successfull/what ever you wanted to show when the data change is complete.

Comment: You can use celery (http://www.celeryproject.org/) to let the task run in a background worker processes which will free the uwsgi porcess to handle the new request. See http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask for an good introdution to the use of celery with flask.

Comment: thank you @syntonym and Sebastian for your comments. I really appreciate your inputs but is there a way to solve this without executing it offline ? Am already using celery in my app but still would like to see if this can be achieved without making it an offline job. And for whoever has downvoted my question, I would like to know the reason as why it was done

Comment: You can use different workers or spawn more but fundamentally the answer to "i have some long, blocking operation that is blocking web processing" is "don't do long, blocking operations in web processors".

Comment: @syntonym ok, true. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can do the following:

1. Separate the heavy logic from the function which is being called
   upon @route and move it into a separate place (a file, another
   function, etc)
2. Introduce Celery to run that pieces of heavy logic
   (it will be processed in a separate thread from the @route-decorated functions).
   A quick way of doing this is using Redis as a message broker.
3. Schedule the time-consuming functions from your @route-decorated
   functions in Celery (it is possible to pass parameters as well)

This way the HTTP requests won't be blocked for the complete function execution time.

Comment: That's a viable solution @Igor . Am using celery and redis for some offline operations but before going ahead implementing what you have suggested, I would like to see if there is another way of doing this without doing it offline. Like bringing up a separate instance of the server just to take care of this request, synchronously. Not through celery or some queueing mechanisms.